# ¿Cómo ejecutar un fichero .SQL desde Laravel y hacer rollback de ser necesario?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, laravel-8

Estoy pasando un script de PHP a Laravel.

Actualmente tengo:

```
               try 
                {
                    foreach($queries as $q)
                    {
                        if($query != '')
                        {
                            $stmt = $pdo->prepare($q);
                            $stmt->execute();
                        }
                    }
                    Log::info('Running commit.');
                    $pdo->commit();
                } 
                catch(\Exception $message) 
                {
                    if ($pdo->inTransaction())
                    {
                        $pdo->rollBack();
                    }        
                }
```

Y según he leído, en Laravel debería hacer:

```
DB::unprepared(file_get_contents(‘database/migrations/mysql.sql’));
```

**Dudas:**

¿Puedo crear directorios dentro del directorio "database/migrations/" para organizar las SQL o sería mala práctica?

¿Cómo puedo pasarlo a Laravel pero seguir teniendo control sobre las SQL? Quiero tener la posibilidad de hacer rollback